# Typescript. Not able to run function properly

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im trying to get this function "this.kill()" to work. But when i call it i get this error: "TypeError: this.kill is not a function" and i cant figure out a way to solve it.

html:

```
<div class="message success" id="alert"></div>
```

Baseclass:

```
export class BaseMessage {

  constructor(protected element:HTMLElement, protected message:string) {
    this.init();
  }

  init():void {
    this.setText(this.message);
    this.addListeners();
  }

  kill():void {
    this.removeListeners();
  }

  setText(message:string):void {
    this.element.textContent = message;
  }

  addListeners():void {
    this.element.addEventListener('click',this.onClick);
  }

  removeListeners():void {
    this.element.removeEventListener('click',this.onClick);
  }

  onClick():void {
    this.kill();
    //its this that causes the error
  }
}
```

Message class

```
import { BaseMessage } from './basemessage';

export class Message extends BaseMessage {
    constructor(element:HTMLElement, message:string) {
        super(element, message);
    }
}
```

Main

```
import { Message } from './components/message';
const mess = document.getElementById('alert');
const message = new Message(mess,'Tack, tack!');
```

Comment: Should be `this.element.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this))`

Comment: Doh, of course it should..